# Maximize the minimum element

Tags: arrays, algorithm

We have an array of N positive elements. We can perform M operations on this array. In each operation we have to select a subarray(contiguous) of length W and increase each element by 1. Each element of the array can be increased at most K times.
We have to perform these operations such that the minimum element in the array is maximized.

1 <= N, W <= 10^5

1 <= M, K <= 10^5

Time limit: 1 sec

I can think of an O(n^2) solution but it is exceeding time limit. Can somebody provide an O(nlogn) or better solution for this?

P.S.- This is an interview question

Comment: What is your `O(n^2)` solution? Post it here please, however trivial you think it may be.

Comment: You might also want to ask this question on this other exchange community: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Will be quite difficult to reach that -1 sec limit, did you try with a time machine? Maybe you mean <1 sec, right?

Comment: Everytime we will find the minimum element and then find the window containing the minimum element having smaller elements and increase each by 1. We will do this M times. Finally, the minimum element of the array will be the answer. I can only think of this.

Comment: _We have to perform these operations such that the minimum element in the array is maximized_ - I've read this through several times and I still don't know with any certainty what this means.

Comment: We have to do these operations such that the smallest element in the array after these operations is as large as possible.

Comment: @juandemarco I'd say http://cs.stackexchange.com suites better. cstheory is much more about theoretical concepts than about problems.

Comment: @SumitKumar: Your solution seems to ignore the possibility that N < M+W, K <= M and K < W all hold: In this situation, every possible placement of M operations causes at least one element to be increased more than W > K times.

Comment: Something is missing in question and it's not possible that you increment all elements by 1 and minimum is maximized?

Answer (score 1):

It was asked in a Google interview and I solved it by using sliding window, heap and increment in a range logic. I will solve the problem in 3 parts:

1. Finding out the minimum of every subarray of size W. This can be done in **O(n)** by using sliding window with priority queue. The maximum of every window must be inserted into a **min-heap** with 3 variable: [array_value, left_index, right_index]
2. Now, make auxiliary array initialised to 0 with of size N. Perform pop operation on heap **M** number of times and in each pop operation perform 3 task:

   **value, left_index, right_index = heap.pop() # theoretical function to pop minimum**

   Increment the value by 1,
   increment by 1 in auxiliary array at left_index and decrement by 1 in
   auxiliary array at right_index+1

   Again insert this pair into heap. [with incremented value and same indexes]
3. After performing M operations traverse the given array with auxiliary array and add the cumulative sum till index 'i' to element at index 'i' in array.

Return minimum of array.

#### Time Complexity

**O(N)** <- for minimum element in every window + building heap.

**O(M*logN)** <- Extracting and inserting into heap.

**O(N)** <- For traversing to add cumulative sum.

So, overall is **O(N + M*logN + N)** which is **O(M*logN)**

#### Space Complexity

**O(N)** <- Extra array + heap.

Few things can be easily optimised above like inserting values in heap, only left_index can be inserted and as right_index = left_index + k.

#### My Code

```py
from heapq import heappop, heappush
from collections import deque


def find_maximised_minimum(arr, n, m, k):

    """
    arr -> Array, n-> Size of array
    m -> increment operation that can be performed
    k -> window size
    """

    heap = []
    q = deque()
    # sliding window + heap building
    for i in range(k):
        while q and arr[q[-1]] > arr[i]:
            q.pop()
        q.append(i)

    for i in range(k, n):
        heappush(heap, [arr[q[0]], i - k, i - 1])
        while q and q[0] <= i - k:
            q.popleft()
        while q and arr[q[-1]] > arr[i]:
            q.pop()
        q.append(i)
    
    heappush(heap, [arr[q[0]], n - k, n - 1])

    # auxiliary array
    temp = [0 for i in range(n)]

    # performing M increment operations
    while m:
        top = heappop(heap)
        temp[top[1]] += 1
        try:
            temp[top[2] + 1] -= 1
        except:
            # when the index is last, so just ignore
            pass
        top[0] += 1
        heappush(heap, top)
        m -= 1

    # finding cumulative sum 
    sumi = 0
    for i in range(n):
        sumi += temp[i]
        arr[i] += sumi
    print(min(arr))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # find([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 6, 5, 2)
    # find([73, 77, 60, 100, 94, 24, 31], 7, 9, 1)
    # find([24, 41, 100, 70, 97, 89, 38, 68, 41, 93], 10, 6, 5)
    # find([88, 36, 72, 72, 37, 76, 83, 18, 76, 54], 10, 4, 3)
    find_maximised_minimum([98, 97, 23, 13, 27, 100, 75, 42], 8, 5, 1)
```

Comment: Just for clarification, Not sure if I am understanding it wrong, When we are inserting again, there might be chance, that same number might present in minHeap with other window (leftIndex and rightIndex).

Answer (score 1):

We can do binary search on the answer. Now say that we want the minimum to be k. Iterate over the array, if v [i] is less than k, add k — v [i] to the next s elements (i.e. i to i + s — 1), this operation costs k — v [i]. If number of such operations is less than or equal to M then increase k else decrease k.

Time Complexity = nlogn

Here is My Code :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int n = 6;
    int m = 5;
    int s = 2;
    int l = 0,h=1e9;
    int ans = 0;
    while(l<=h){
        int mid = l + (h-l)/2;
        int need = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i+=s){
            if(v[i] < mid){
                need += mid - v[i];
            }
        }
        if(need <= m){
            l = mid + 1;
            ans = mid;
        }else{
            h = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    cout << ans << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What if we kept a copy of the array sorted ascending, pointing each element to its original index? Think about the order of priority when incrementing the elements. Also, does the final order of operations matter?

Once the lowest element reaches the next lowest element, what must then be incremented? And if we apply `k` operations to any one element does it matter in which `w` those increments were applied?